# Cross Domain XML to Javascript from PHP

Tags: javascript, php, xml, json, cross-domain

I want to send XML data from php(domain **A**) to a remote javascript file(domain **B**).
I can't have them on the same domain, and I can't have any other files on on domain B.

I've read about sending a JSONP object from php instead of XML, but as I understood from a tutorial, I would need a php proxy on the same domain as where the javascript file is located. [tutorial link](http://www.sitepoint.com/php-xml-to-json-proxy/)
(*xhr.open("GET", "xmlproxy.php?url=" + escape(url), true);* <= this line kinda tells me, that the xmlproxy.php has to be on the same domain as the actuala javascript)

Any suggestions, on how could I do this?

**LATER EDIT AFTER ThW's answer**

Now I have the following sample code :

The testlog.php file

```
<?php header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    print "<Logs><Log><id>Test Log</id></Log></Logs>";
?>
```

The javascript function that is called on page load:

```
function getTestLog() {
    alert("Gets here!");
    $.ajax({
        url: "anotherdomain/testlog.php",
        data: requestVars,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){
            alert(xml);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert("Error: " + xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nerror:" + err);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is, that it's not getting into the ajax thing

Comment: JSONP does not require you to use proxy... Please tell us how much data do you need to transfer? It is important.

Comment: Imagine a playlist with 100 tracks and for every track there would be artist, track title, and duration. I can't really estimate the exact size of the data chunk, but that's the closest I can think of. Thank you for replying by the way. On a side note : I have access to both the php and the javascript files, but I cannot add any other files to the same domain where the javascript is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control the PHP that outputs the XML you can use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

By default Javascript can only open resources from the domain it was loaded. Other resources have to allow that they can be loaded by a Javascript on a different domain.

To do that add a header to the PHP-Script:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://javascript-domain.tld');
```

Or to allow the loading of the XML from anywhere:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

You're using jQuery and here might be a problem if you're not sending the correct content type from PHP.

```
header('Content-Type: application/xml');
```

To validate that it is the Cross Domain that it is blocking the reading open you Javascript console in the browser. It should output an error message. In Firefox it is something like:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading 
the remote resource at http://domain.tld/path/to/resource. This can be fixed by 
moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS
```

If you get the request, it should show up in the Network-Tab of your developer tools and you can validate the HTTP response headers.

Here is simple JS snippet using XHR, it forces the content type.:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.overrideMimeType("application/xml");
xhr.addEventListener(
  'load',
  function (xhr) {
    return function () {
      if (xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 400) {
        console.log(xhr.responseXML);
      }
    }
  }(xhr)
);
xhr.open('GET', 'http://php-domain.tld/script.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/xml");
xhr.send();
```

Comment: I edited my question with code examples because I can't get it to work.
Thank you for helping ThW!

Comment: Doesn't work is not really a useful error description. You need to debug WHAT doesn't work. I added some information about how.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
This answer helped me alot.
Now I need to get an ssl for the second domain, where the php file is, and it's ready to go (the javascripts secured domain is not allowed to call a domain without SSL)